# filter the items inside *ngFor based on the category on button click - Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular-pipe

I have a list of items which I am looping through with *ngFor. I have category buttons above the list like in the HTML shown below. What I need to implement is when clicking on the button, I want to filter the list based on the category of the button clicked.

I am not sure what approach is better, whether to go for a pipe or just a function

```
<div class="quick-filter-container">
    <button class="quick-filter-button active" [class.active]="isActive('cat1')" (click)="setActive('cat1')"
        type="button">Category1</button>
    <button class="quick-filter-button" [class.active]="isActive('cat2')" (click)="setActive('cat2')"
        type="button">Category2</button>
    <button class="quick-filter-button" [class.active]="isActive('cat3')" (click)="setActive('cat3')"
        type="button">Category3</button>
    <button class="quick-filter-button" [class.active]="isActive('cat4')" (click)="setActive('cat4')"
        type="button">Category4</button>
</div>


<div class="meter-reading-list-conatiner" *ngFor="let data of filteredList">
    <h1>{{data.address.addressName}}</h1>
    <div *ngFor="let header of data.premiseMeters"> 
        <span> ID: {{header.meterNumber}}</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
setActive(buttonName) {
 this.activeButton = buttonName;
 }
isActive(buttonName) {
return this.activeButton === buttonName;
}
```

JSON

```
this.filteredList = {
  "meterReadPanelReportList": [
    {
      "premiseId": 674052,
      "address": {
        "addressName": "CHILDRENS ROAD, LIMERICK, CO. LIMERICK"
      },
      "premiseMeters": [
        {
          "meterNumber": "Y00001410",
          "utilType": "elec",
          "category": "category1",
          "meters": [
            {
              "lastReadingDate": "23/09/2020",
              "lastReadingMethod": "E",
              "lastReadingStatus": "Pending"
            },
            {
              "lastReadingDate": "24/09/2020",
              "lastReadingMethod": "E",
              "lastReadingStatus": "Pending"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "meterNumber": "Z00001410",
          "utilType": "gas",
          "category": "category3",
          "meters": [
            {
              "lastReadingDate": "23/09/2020",
              "lastReadingMethod": "E",
              "lastReadingStatus": "Pending"
            },
            {
              "lastReadingDate": "23/09/2020",
              "lastReadingMethod": "E",
              "lastReadingStatus": "Pending"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "premiseId": 674052,
      "address": {
        "addressName": "CHILDRENS ROAD, LIMERICK, CO. LIMERICK"
      },
      "premiseMeters": [
        {
          "meterNumber": "Y00001410",
          "utilType": "gas",
          "category": "category2",
          "meters": [
            {
              "lastReadingDate": "23/09/2020",
              "lastReadingMethod": "E",
              "lastReadingStatus": "Pending"
            },
            {
              "lastReadingDate": "24/09/2020",
              "lastReadingMethod": "E",
              "lastReadingStatus": "Pending"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "meterNumber": "Z00001410",
          "utilType": "gas",
          "category": "category3",
          "meters": [
            {
              "lastReadingDate": "23/09/2020",
              "lastReadingMethod": "E",
              "lastReadingStatus": "Pending"
            },
            {
              "lastReadingDate": "23/09/2020",
              "lastReadingMethod": "E",
              "lastReadingStatus": "Pending"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: you can filter the array simply use a *ngIf: `<ng-contaner *ngIf="data.category==your_variable"><h1..><div>...</div><ng-container>`

Answer (score 0):

Call the function from html and pass the category name as an argument

```
<button class="quick-filter-button active" [class.active]="isActive('cat1')" (click)="myClickFunction('category1')"
    type="button">Category1</button>
```

Filter the data in components on a common function. Expecting the unfiltered dataset named as `data` here.

```
myClickFunction(category){
      this.filteredList = data.filter(item => item.category === category );
}
```